# pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen делает скриншоты

Tags: python, linux, pyautogui

Пытаюсь запустить такой код:

```
def click_in():
    while True:
        try:
            coordinate_whell = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(
                image='image.jpg',
                confidence=0.5,
            )
            pyautogui.click(coordinate_whell.x, coordinate_whell.y)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Всё корректно отрабатывает, так, как я ожидаю, но почему-то после каждого запуска в папку с проектом сохраняются скриншоты PyCharm в момент запуска программы. Называются всегда примерно так:

```
.screenshot2023-1211_23-20-38-130629.png
```

Знаю, что можно делать скриншоты через `pyautogui.screenshot('name.png')`, но у меня этого нет в коде, я просто ищу элемент на экране. Не помню, чтобы раньше каждый раз сохранялся снимок после запуска. Пожалуйста, помогите это исправить

Comment: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html

Comment: @ClarkDevlin, в этом и проблема, что я не вызываю `screenshot()`

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze/commit/eeca245a135cf171c163b3691300138518efa64e#diff-edcdafb16305fe4747c08e7f8913fabb4030b769d5d204c6672d949b9daaee0aR596

В новой версии временный файл создается в любом случае кроме случая когда установлен PILLOW версии 9.2.0 и новее.

Comment: У меня стоит `Pillow 10.1.0`, но это всё равно происходит. По вашей ссылке в коде там есть комментарий на 624 строке - "To take screenshots, you must install Pillow version 9.2.0 or greater and gnome-screenshot by running `sudo apt install gnome-screenshot`' # noqa". Т.е. для того, чтобы делать скриншот, нужна версия > 9.2.0? Или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: pyscreeze у вас какой версии?

Comment: такой библиотеки вообще не стояло, установил 0.1.30

Comment: Значит была в составе пайаутогуи. Обнови и его на свежее